# Agregar un elemento como llave, sin valor a un diccionario en python, armar diccionarios canonicos

Tags: python, json, map

Mi función debe crear un diccionario con la siguiente estrucutra, a partir de un vector de llaves y un vector de valores, reemplazando los lugares k1, con la primer llave y v1 con el primer valor, y asi sucesivamente. La idea es hacer un diccionario canonico

```
{k1: {k2: v1},k3: [v2, v3, v4...]}
```

Mi problema es que mi función recibe distintos inputs, que generalmente son objetos json, y a la hora de recibir un objeto json, con menos de dos llaves, el segundo valor del json se perderia dado que nunca podria existir k3, entonces, querria saber que ideas me proponen para solventar este probleama.

Input con dos keys:

```
{
"time": "2022-04-07T12:53:39.302+0300",
"user": "Basic PGxvZ2luPg=="
```

}

Otro input con mas de dos keys:

```
[
{ "name": "George", "id": 12, "email": "george@domain.com" },
{ "name": "Jack", "id": 18, "email": "jack@domain.com" },
{ "name": "Joe", "id": 19, "email": "joe@domain.com" }
```

]

Función que procesa los datos, para llegar al objetivo descripto anteriormente:

```
def obatain_candict2(vec_keys, values_list):
can_dict = {}

if len(vec_keys) <= 2:
    for i in range(len(vec_keys)):
        if i  == 0:
            can_dict[vec_keys[0]] = {}
        elif i == 1:
            can_dict[vec_keys[0]][vec_keys[i]] = []
            for j in range(len(values_list)):
                can_dict[vec_keys[0]][vec_keys[i]].append(values_list[j])
else:
    for i in range(len(vec_keys)):
        if i == 0:
            can_dict[vec_keys[0]] = {}
        elif i == 1:
            can_dict[vec_keys[0]][vec_keys[i]] = values_list[0]
        elif i == 2:
            can_dict[vec_keys[i]] = []
            for j in range(len(values_list)):
                if j == 0:
                    continue
                can_dict[vec_keys[i]].append(values_list[j])
return can_dict
```

Output hasta ahora:

```
{'time': {'user': ['2022-04-07T12:53:39.302+0300', 'Basic PGxvZ2luPg==']}}

{'name': {'id': 'George'}, 'email': [12, 'george@domain.com', 'Jack', 18, 'jack@domain.com', 'Joe', 19, 'joe@domain.com']}
```

Comment: No están claras las reglas para armar el diccionario. Los ejemplos ayudan, pero no dan toda la información.

Comment: Claro es que la verdad yo tampoco termino de comprender, dado que solo me han dado la estructura base, que en este caso es la mostrada:
{k1: {k2: v1},k3: [v2, v3, v4...]}